# Docusign: how can I send documents to signer / recipients once they have signed or when envelope is complete?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I noticed that in a workflow where contracts are sent to signers by Docusign by email, all signers receive the signed documents once the envelope is complete.
In my case, I am using the embedded signing scenario: signers sign via our application in an `iFrame`. My wish is that signers receive contracts signed like in the first workflow, when the envelope is completed.

I'm currently using a test app and receive no email when envelope has completed.

How can I turn that on ? Or trigger it via API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reaching out. Firstly, I would discourage your to use `iFrame` - our IDV service won't work in `iFrame` and there is currently no plan to support it.

When you use embedded signing, it's up to you to manage documents as you wish. In your case, I suggest you setup DocuSign Connect https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/

When the event for envelope completed comes in, you can get the completed document and send it to everyone in the envelope.